# OWL API axioms with short prefixes

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

OWL API in Java offers working with set of axioms through:

```
domainOntology.getAxioms()
```

All axioms have long prefixes by default, e.g.:

```
ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#locatedIn> <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#TexasRegion> <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#USRegion>)
```

How can I transform the axioms to axioms with short prefixes, e.g:

```
ObjectPropertyAssertion( wine:locatedIn wine:TexasRegion wine:USRegion )
```

Ontology can of course have more prefixes defined (not only e.g. "wine")

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the `toString()` value; that's for debugging purposes, not for further processing.

Depending on what exactly you wish to achieve, you might be better off picking a language that supports prefixes (e.g., Manchester OWL Syntax or Functional Syntax), set the prefixes you wish yo use and render the axioms:

```
FunctionalSyntaxDocumentFormat format=new FunctionalSyntaxDocumentFormat();
format.setPrefix("ont", "http://test.com/ontology");
ontology.saveOntology(format, System.out);
```

Comment: I think that the answer for me is somewhere in your response. Could you please tell me how can I display any axiom from the ontology in a short prefix form e.g. ObjectPropertyRange(food:hasFood food:EdibleThing). I do not want to modify ontology original prefix (format.setPrefix)

Comment: The code I've shown does not modify the original format of the ontology. The call to save is simply to display the ontology on standard output. You can create a new ontology containing only one axiom if you wish to display the axioms separately, or look at ToStringRenderer to modify the default toString()

Comment: I updated the OWL Api to check it. What type is "ontology" in your code in line ontology.saveOntology? Still, I do not think that this code will shorten the origianal prefixes

Comment: OWLOntology - created with an OWLOntologyManager, in turn created with OWLManager.

Comment: I cannot make the FunctionalSyntaxDocumentFormat (and your code) working. I am using OWLFunctionalSyntaxOntologyFormat.

Comment: Are you using owlapi version 3? I would recommend updating to a more recent version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a prefix, take for example the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select * where {
SERVICE <http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql/> {
    SELECT * where {
       ?value rdfs:label "Personaggi dei fumetti"@it .
       ?title <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?value . 
       OPTIONAL {?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/firstAppearance> ?start_date .   
   }
       OPTIONAL {?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/author> ?author . }
       OPTIONAL {?title <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/paese> ?country .} 
       OPTIONAL {?title <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/sesso> ?gender .}  
       OPTIONAL {?title <http://it.dbpedia.org/property/dataInizio> ?date .}
   }
}
}
```

Using the `PREFIX` keyword when setting up the query allows you to use the prefixed word as a substitution for the URL that it relates to.

Comment: Of course, I know this. I am asking for geting short prefixes through OWL API from Java code.

Comment: @Annabelle ah ok, don't know the Java API, thought this might help you anyway.